# What's the correct usage of $.extend(deep, target, obj)? My code won't work

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with the $.extend function, see the code below...

```
//Function to merge the opts with the defaultOpts

var foo = function(opts){
    var opts = opts ? opts : {};

    console.log('BEFORE: ');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(opts));

    var defaultOpts = {
        className  : 'defaultClass',
        selectable : false,
        ID         : null,
        buttons    : []
    }   

    $.extend(true, opts, defaultOpts);

    console.log('AFTER: ');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(opts));
}

//Run the function and pass in a few options

foo({
    className : 'realClassName',
    buttons   : [
        {
            something : 'nothing'
        },
        {
            something : 'nothing'
        }
    ]
});
```

The problem with the output is that the "className" property is being replaced by the default value, but for some reason the "buttons" property works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$.extend(true, opts, defaultOpts, opts);
```

or:

```
var nuOpts = {};
$.extend(true, nuOpts, defaultOpts, opts);
opts = nuOpts;
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one works but not the first. I understand my mistake now :)

Comment: Also, this one works just as well: $.extend(true, {}, defaultOpts, opts);

Comment: no, because you just fill up "{}" which can't be adressed in ANY way after your statement!?

Comment: Sorry,  opts = $.extend(true, {}, defaultOpts, opts);